# Express using logic symbols:

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have to also decide whether it is true or not after I express it in logic symbols. This is what I have so far..Am I correct? and I don't know how to do a)..

a) There is a smallest positive number

-no idea how to approach this one? Perhaps somehow denote this as infinity? and how can I even state a true/false value? Is this even a statement?

b) Every integer is a product of two integers

True: (x,y belong to the set of integers): ∀x∀y(x * y = (set of integers))

c) The equation x^2+y^2 = 1 has a solution (x,y) in which both x and y are natural numbers

True: (x,y belong to the set of natural numbers): ∀x∀y(x^2+y^2 = 1)

d) Every real number can be written as a difference of two positive real numbers

True: (x,y belong to the set of real numbers): ∀x∀y(x-y = (set of real numbers))

Thank you very much!

Comment: Mac, I don't think your transcriptions of b, c, and d say what you think they say. For example, in c $\forall x \forall y ( x^2+y^2 = 1)$ means that the sum of squares of ANY two natural numbers is one. This is clearly false. When a statement asserts that somethings exists, you should think about using existential quantifiers, not universal ones.

Comment: Mac, per your request below, I believe that b and d are also incorrect as written. Your b seems to say "For any integers x and y, the product of x and y is the set of integers" which is not what you intended to write. You might also mean "For any integers x and y, the product of x and y is in the set of integers" which is true but also not what you intended to write. For d your translation says "For any real numbers x and y, x-y is (or is in) the real numbers" which has the same problems.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the two most direct ways to say that there is no smallest positive number:

$$\begin{align*}
&\neg\exists x\forall y(y>0\to y\ge x)\\
&\forall x\big(x>0\to\exists y(y>0\land y<x)\big)
\end{align*}$$

In words:

- There is no number $x$ such that whenever $y$ is positive, $y$ is at least as large as $x$.
- For every positive number $x$ there is a positive number $y$ that is smaller than $x$.

Your formula for (b) does not say what you want it to say: it says that the product of any two integers whatsoever is the set of integers. That’s clearly not right: the product is an integer, not the whole set of integers. But even if you changed it to $\forall x\forall y(xy\in\Bbb Z)$, which is at least a true statement (meaning that the product of any $x$ and $y$ is an integer), it wouldn’t say what you want. You want to say that whenever $x$ is an integer, **there are** integers $y$ and $z$ whose product is $x$. Notice the existence statement there: you’re almost certainly going to want some existential quantifiers. And in fact the English translates pretty directly into symbols: $\forall x\exists y\exists z(yz=x)$. Note, though, that this works only if it’s understood that that $x,y$, and $z$ range over the integers. If not, you have to specify that as well, either as

$$\forall x\in\Bbb Z\exists y\in\Bbb Z\exists z\in\Bbb Z(yz=x)$$

or, more formally, as

$$\forall x\Big(x\in\Bbb Z\to\exists y\exists z(y\in\Bbb Z\land z\in\Bbb Z\land yz=x\Big)\;.$$

Your answer to (c) is also wrong, I’m afraid: you’ve said that no matter what real numbers you substitute for $x$ and $y$, $x^2+y^2$ will be $1$. The sentence that you’re supposed to be translating makes a much weaker claim: it says that there is at least one pair of numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$. That’s $\exists x\in\Bbb R\exists y\in\Bbb R\left(x^2+y^2=1\right)$.

In (d) you’ve made the same kind of mistake as in (b). It makes no sense to say that $x-y$ is equal to the whole bloomin’ set of real numbers: it’s just one real number! And when we fix that, so that it says $\forall x\in\Bbb R\forall y\in\Bbb R(x-y\in\Bbb R)$, we’re just saying that if you take the difference of two real numbers, you get a real number. That’s **not** the same as saying that if you start with any real number $x$, you can find two real numbers whose difference is $x$, which is what you’re supposed to be saying. That requires a couple of existential quantifiers: $$\forall x\in\Bbb R\exists y\in\Bbb R\exists z\in\Bbb R(y-z=x)\;.$$ Structurally this is exactly like (b).

Answer (score 0):

There is a smallest positive number $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall a, b \in R : a - b > \epsilon$. This is denoted as $\mathbf{epsilon}$.

The second one would be similar to yours:

$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}[\exists a, b \in \mathbb{Z} : ab = x]$

I think these provide enough hints for you to finish.

Comment: Your second one is correct but is **not** similar to the OP’s incorrect version; your first is not correct.

Comment: @DonLarynx Can I also denote the small number as (1/infinity) instead of using the epsilon(haven't learned this yet)? Also, my other assumptions correct? (with the exception of c)? Thanks for you reply!

Comment: @Mac: No, you cannot, and you should ignore Don’s comments on (a); they are at best irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What can be fixed? I have always attributed this definition to $\epsilon$?

Comment: In the context of the real numbers the Greek letter $\epsilon$ is typically used to denote some small positive real number, but this is merely a notational convention, a tradition; it has no generally defined meaning.

Comment: What is different between mine and yours? mine says the same thing as yours, that there exists a number such that the difference is greater than 0. but less than any real. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: No, yours does not say the same thing as mine, even after you add the missing quantifier and make it $$\exists\epsilon\in\Bbb R\Big(\epsilon>0\land\forall a\in\Bbb R\forall b\in\Bbb R(a-b>\epsilon)\Big)\;.$$ Yours says that there is a positive real number that is smaller than any possible difference of real numbers; mine says that there is a positive real number that is less than or equal to every positive real number. These differ in at least three important ways. First, yours implies that $\epsilon$ is not the difference of two positive reals: if it were, $\epsilon>\epsilon$ would be ...

Comment: ... true. Secondly, since $1-2=-1$, and $1$ and $2$ are positive reals, yours implies that $-1>\epsilon$; that is clearly not implied by the original statement. And finally, yours says only that **differences** are bounded below by some positive number; the original says that **positive real numbers** are bounded below by some positive number.

Answer (score 0):

I will show the first problem for you. We are talking about a smallest positive number, let's call this number $a$. Then the number $a$ has two properties:

$\bullet$ $a$ is positive, or in formal language: $a \in \mathbb{R}_+$.
$\bullet$ $a$ is the smallest positive number, so any other positive number $b$ is greater or equal to $a$.

We can then write the statement "there exists a smallest positive number" as follows: $\exists a \in \mathbb{R}_+ \forall b \in \mathbb{R}_+ : a \leq b$.

Can you solve the other problems now?

Answer (score 0):

A) "There is a smallest positive number" should be

$$ \exists N \in PositiveNumbers : smallest(N) $$

Any clarification of the concept of numbers and smallest is speculation and thus not logically correct.